# Is it safe to get user data with code eval("\$name= \"$input\";"), where $input gets from user?

Tags: php, eval, user-input, code-injection

```
$input = $_GET['name'];
eval("\$name= \"$input\";");
```

Or it is insecure? Thanks. Without any php functions, like preg_replace or any other, just working with user data as string type with \" when put it to eval function.

Comment: No, it's most definitely is not

Comment: If you tell us what exactly you're trying to accomplish, Someone might give you a safe alternative

Comment: Please, do not do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

This basically will allow the user to inject arbitrary code into your application. Think something in the line of

```
$input=";mysql_query(\"DROP TABLE users\")"
```

Also eval makes it basically impossible to cache anything but that is a minor consequence.